# attempt to compare nil with number stack traceback?

Tags: lua

I'm playing with Lua following this link: https://www.lua.org/pil/4.2.html  and get confused about a point.

```
Lua 5.2.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2015 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> x=10
> local i=1
> while i<=x do
>>  local x = i*2
>>  print(x)
>>  i=i+1
>> end
stdin:1: attempt to compare nil with number
stack traceback:
    stdin:1: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?
```

I guess this error message indicates that something is wrong with the expression `while i<=x`. Any comments are greatly appreciated. 
**EDIT:** I just realize that it's probably because it does not work in a terminal.

Comment: cant reproduce it on https://repl.it , there is nothing wrong with the code as it is

Comment: @AndrewKashpur `repl.it` doesn't provide a console, but [as you see](https://repl.it/languages/lua) a `main.lua` that can be run.

Answer (score 3):

It did not work out in an interactive terminal. Because `local i=1` is understood by terminal as a chunk by itself once you hit enter. That is why the "attempt to compare nil with number" error; because i is not defined, i.e., nil in this case. To correct it, put the first two lines and the while loop inside of a do chuck as the following.

```
> do
>>  x = 10
>>  local i=1
>>  while i<=x do
>>    local x = i*2
>>    print(x)
>>    i = i+1
>>  end
>> end
2
4
6
8
10
12
14
16
18
20
>
```

Comment: Interesting: The `do` obviously starts a new "scope for locals" or *chunk* in the Lua terminology?

Comment: @Wolf `do` starts a [block](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.3.1). Syntactically a chunk is a block, but they are handled differently. Blocks are good in controling the scopes of variables. Anyway, in Lua interpreter you could omit outer `do` block for a simple: `local i = 1 while i <= x do` (in a single line).

Comment: @kkxx You can accept your answer as a correct one. There is no shame in that. Ha! There is even a badge for that IIRC.

Answer (score 2):

Actually the problem is in `local i=1` try

```lua
> local i = 1
> print(i)
```

The problem is that when running the console, it seems that the line is a chunk and the variable is local inside that chunk.
you can fix that by using a global variable or you can do this

```lua
> local i = 1 do
>> print(i)
>> end
```

Which results in chunk structure like this `[local i [print(i)]]` therefore i can be accessed. Note also that `local x = i*2` is valid since it is inside the `while - do` chunk.

Your code would also work correctly, if it was inside a Lua file.

Comment: I tried it out and it worked inside a Lua file. The thing is, inside of a Lua file, how to define a "chunk"?

Comment: @kkxx When you load a file, all of its top level content is considered a main chunk. Just see it: play around with `luac -l`.

Comment: @kkxx Chunks are usually made when you use `if` (the parts between keywords `if then` `elseif then` `else` `end`), `while` and `for` also `function`s are separate chunks. If you want to define a chunk that does not fulfill any of these functions (only to limit a scoope of a local variable) you can always use `do` [chunk] `end`. You can also execute another file using `dofile()` for example, where the executed file is a chunk itself.

Answer (score 1):

I could reproduce the problem in Lua 5.3.4 as well.

If you read on in the [Lua docs, chapter 4.2 – Local Variables and Blocks](https://www.lua.org/pil/4.2.html), you'll get to the sentence

> Beware that this example will not work as expected if you enter it in interactive mode. The second line, local i = 1, is a complete chunk by itself.

This addresses exactly the issue in question. So it seems that the Lua interpreter has limited support for an outmost chunk (that is clearly present in a Lua file). But this behaviour seems to me acceptable and understandable in view of the compactness of language and interpreter.

So, **when in interactive mode,**

**either** leave out the `local` before variable `i` to make it work:

```
Lua 5.3.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2017 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
Lua>x=10
Lua>i=1
Lua>while i<=x do
...>local x=i*2
...>print(x)
...>i=i+1
...>end
```

**or** start enclose the whole by a block:

```
Lua 5.3.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2017 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
Lua>do
...>local x=10
...>local i=1
...>while i<=x do
...>local x=i*2
...>print(x)
...>i=i+1
...>end
...>end
```

Both options will produce to the regular (and expected) output:

```
2
4
6
8
10
12
14
16
18
20
```

Comment: it's because when you left out 'local' before variable i, it is considered as global. Then both i and x have values to compare in the while loop.

Comment: @kkxx Yes, obviously, thanks for having a look on it. Meanwhile the documentation clarified the confusion about chunks and local.

Comment: I got it. The whole Lua file is considered as a chunk. ;)