# the difference between loadstring and a normal function definition in Lua?

Tags: lua

I'm playing with Lua, following the link: https://www.lua.org/pil/8.html. And I got confused a bit...

```
> i = 100
> local i=3
> f=loadstring("i=i+1")
> print(i)
100
> g=function() i=i+1 end
> print(i)
100
> f()
> print(i)
101
> g()
> print(i)
102
```

I mean, why neither f nor g use the local i?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have an answer for that in [one of your previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58726081/attempt-to-compare-nil-with-number-stack-traceback).

```
> local i=3
```

Since you are using Lua interpreter in interactive mode, the local `i` is only visible in the chunk I have quoted above. Hence, both `f` and `g` increase global `i` as they don't see local `i` from the chunk quoted.

Consider writing your Lua code to a file and then executing them via e.g.: `lua file.lua`.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me. I'm reading https://www.lua.org/pil/8.html; So the question should not be about the differences between loadstring and other normal functions.